# Reset level 1 indexes individually for every level 0 index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Say I have the following DataFrame:

```
                    col1    col2
index0    index1
A         0           10     nan
          1           11      31
          2           12      32
B         0           20     nan
          1           21      41
          2           22      42
```

I want to now drop all rows with nans, leave the level 0 indexes as they are, and then reset each of the level 1 indexes so that they start from 0 again:

```
>>> df.dropna(inplace=True)

                    col1    col2
index0    index1
A         1           11      31
          2           12      32
B         1           21      41
          2           22      42

>>> somehow reset the level 1 indexes

                    col1    col2
index0    index1
A         0           11      31
          1           12      32
B         0           21      41
          1           22      42
```

Comment: The only thing I can find with regards to the index levels is the `level` parameter of `df.reset_index()`. I have tried `df.reset_index(level=1, inplace=True, drop=True)`, but this got rid of all level 1 indexes, and set the level 1 as the only index for each row.

Comment: I have also tried iterating over the level 0 indexes, call each one `i` and tried `df.loc[i].reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)`, which did nothing and I don't understand why?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=df.dropna()
s.assign(index1=s.groupby(level=0).cumcount()).set_index('index1',append=True).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
Out[1210]: 
               col1  col2
index0 index1            
A      0         11  31.0
       1         12  32.0
B      0         21  41.0
       1         22  42.0
```